# How do I get bazel autocomplete to start working again?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, clion, bazel

I work at a large company that recently started using Bazel for compiling instead of cmake which I was more familiar with. Recently my bazel autocomplete stopped working, which is quite important in my case since I have to write these long, clunky build statements.

Simultaneously my Clion with built in bazel plugin stopped reading symbols. I assume these two issues are related.

I am pretty sure that I have only one bazel installation on my computer.

```
$ which bazel
  /usr/local/bin/bazel
$ which bazel-real
  /usr/local/bin/bazel-real
$ whereis bazel
  bazel: /usr/local/bin/bazel /usr/local/lib/bazel
$ whereis bazel-real
  bazel-real: /usr/local/bin/bazel-real
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Bazel v0.19.1, Bazel plugin v2018.04.23.0.4, CLion v2017.3.4

Comment: Did you figure out why symbols weren't working?

Comment: I did not find out why the symbols were not working. But I did get them to work again by following : https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/completion.html